# Why does a UDP client send 1Gbit speed to 100Mbit server?

Tags: linux, networking, debugging, troubleshooting, udp

I've just found out that in a simple UDP client/server application I wrote on Linux userspace, the UDP client (1 Gbit Ethernet interface) sends the data with 1 Gbit speed to a UDP server which has only a 100 Mbit Ethernet interface. Of course this leads to massive packet loss on the server side.

I have to adjust the NIC settings by doing this on client side:

ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg on

Why do I have to do this? Shoudn't this be handled automatically?

Comment: UDP is quite dumb so does not have the error handling or feedback that might be found in, say, TCP streams. By design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) is a “fire-and-forget” transport, so it doesn’t care what happens to packets once they’re sent. This means you can send at the egress rate of the source system, regardless of the characteristics of the path to the destination; obviously this leads to packet loss if the source interface can send packets faster than the network can bear.

If you need this to be handled automatically, you need to switch to TCP or SCTP. Alternatively, you can build your own error-handling protocol on top of UDP...

In your specific case, if you can rely on 100Mbits/s to the destination, you’d be better off using traffic shaping on the client, instead of limiting all your traffic to a 100Mbits/s interface speed.

Answer (score 1):

As Stephen already pointed out: UDP lacks the means you want.

If your application is as stupid as it seems then you may enforce a lower speed by setting up a virtual `ipip` interface (`ip link`) between the hosts and using traffic shaping (`tc`) for limiting the used bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers correctly point out, UDP traffic control has to managed at layer-7 level.

If you are the one author of the app, you could define an option for it that:

- defines the number of messages sent per second;
- or the speed of which it generates the traffic for future versions;
- or if it is not multicast, waiting for some sort of acknowledgment on the client side for sending more data.